# Search application content/data in Siri search suggestions

Tags: xamarin.ios, siri

I have a mobile app developed in Xamarin iOS. Device database contains information about employees. Now user need to get into the app search for employee and then his details are fetched. I am thinking to have something like user searches employee name in Siri search and then corresponding information is fetched from app and displayed as a suggestion.
How to implement this using Xamarin iOS ? or what is logic to achieve this ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to achieve this ? Thanks!

Comment: did you attempt to do any research before posting this?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/sirikit/understanding-sirikit